# How to enumerate hard drives

Tags: .net, winforms, hard-drive

I am writing a .net winforms application.  I want to be able to enumerate all of the hard drives on a system.

Furthermore I would love to be able to determine which of the drives is Fixed and Which is removable.

Finally, of the removable drives, I would love to be able to determine which of them is a flash (SSD or thumb) drive versus a standard hard drive.

Answer (score 6):

For the first two points you want the following. I think you might have to switch to WMI to determine if a removable drive is solid state or hard drive based.

```
foreach(DriveInfo info in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
   Console.WriteLine(info.Name + ":" + info.DriveType);
}
```

Produces a list of all the drives and their type from the [DriveType Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI to do that. You'll need either [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx) or [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
{
    if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

But I don't know how you can determine whether it's Flash, SSD or hard drive... maybe with WMI